# Extra mass due to near light like speeds

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light

Why does mass seem to increase as you near the speed of light?

Comment: Well worth  reading, imo: http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/mass-energy-matter-etc/more-on-mass/the-two-definitions-of-mass-and-why-i-use-only-one/

Answer (score 0):

Actually the relativistic mass $E/c^2$ changes while the intrinsic mass (rest mass) stays the same. We use relativistic mass when the mass is moving and the instrinsic mass when the body is at rest.

> Relativistic mass
>
> Main article: Mass in special relativity
>   After Einstein first made his proposal, it became clear that the word mass can have two different meanings. Some denote the relativistic mass with an explicit index:
>
> $m_{\mathrm{rel}} = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ .
>
> This mass is the ratio of momentum to velocity, and it is also the relativistic energy divided by $c^2$ (it is not Lorentz-invariant, in contrast to $m_0$). The equation $E = m_{rel}c^2$ holds for moving objects. When the velocity is small, the relativistic mass and the rest mass are almost exactly the same.
>
> $E = mc^2$ either means $E = m_0c^2$ for an object at rest, or $E = m_{rel}c^2$ when the object is moving.

[image]

> The two interpretations of what “mass” means. The first (in green) is that mass is something that does not change with speed — often called “invariant mass” or “rest mass”, it is used by particle physicists. The other, “relativistic mass”, is just energy divided by c-squared, and grows with speed. Note the two are almost identical at small velocities, and so are usually equal in daily life.

So the intrinsic mass, $m_0$, that we associate with the object at rest stays constant while the relativistic mass, $m_{rel}$, goes to infinity as the velocity increases to the speed of light.